# Need help making script that can loop through subfolders

Tags: powershell

I'm a PS novice so bear with me. I've adopted a one-liner from another PS user that has worked very well to remove data in a folder that is older than 14 days. Problem is, I need the script to navigate through all subfolders of the root directory. Below is the script in its current state (replaced actual path with "`Test`"):

```
Get-ChildItem –Path "D:\Test\Test_1" -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-14))} | Remove-Item
```

Two problems with the above that I'd like to resolved.

1. It's referencing `LastWriteTime` to dictate whether or not it's removed within that 14 day period. It would be more accurate if the script queried for `CreationDate` but I'm having trouble understanding how to make that happen
2. I would like the script to run through Test_1 all the way through Test_9 subfolders, effectively removing all data that exists in those subfolders with a creation date of > 14 days.

Sorry for the lack of brevity, I'm realizing it can be difficult to articulate what I'm looking to accomplish. Thanks!

EDIT: Seems using **CreationTime** works:

```
Get-ChildItem –Path "D:\Test\Test_1" -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-14))} | Remove-Item
```

Comment: You can pass a wildcard `*` to Get-ChildItem like `"D:\Test\Test_*"`.  Would that work for you? Yes, use `$_.CreationTime`

Comment: I just tested it, that seems to do the trick! For clarity's sake, how does PS know which folders to query for first under the wildcard status? i.e. Does it search sequentially (Test_1, Test_2, ect.)?

Comment: Your file system is a linked list and sequentially goes through the list.  What is displayed in File Explorer is sorted (name, date) the way you specify the sorting.  It is not the way it exists in the linked list.  When you add a file to a directory it add to the first available space.  There can be nulls because of files that were deleted.

Comment: The most canonical property to use when someone says "delete xxx older than xxx days" is to use LastWriteTime.  Why is that not working for you?  Maybe you have an unusual use case, but be careful with CreationTime, if the file was copied, it will be the time it was copied and newer than the file's LastWriteTime.